# UIWebView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

guys,

I want to make UITableView, where some of cells is web views.

So, I have html for them loaded.

My code:

```
 NSString *md5HTML = [adm_post_dict[@"html"] MD5];

        SKWebViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:md5HTML];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[SKWebViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:md5HTML];

            cell.owner = self;
            cell.height = [adm_post_dict[@"height"] floatValue];
            cell.html = adm_post_dict[@"html"];
        }

        return cell;
```

SKWebViewCell.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
        webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:webView];

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) prepareForReuse {
    [webView stopLoading];
}
- (void) setHeight:(float)height {
    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, height);
}
- (void) setOwner:(NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate> *)owner {
    [webView setDelegate:owner];
}

- (void) setHtml:(NSString *)html {
    if (![_html isEqualToString:html]) {
        _html = html;

        [webView stopLoading];
        [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>%@</body></html>",html] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stylefie.com/"]];
    }
}


@end
```

Problems:

1. It works on iOS 6, but very slow.
2. It works fast on iOS 7, but sometimes web view doesn't show anything and sending this to console:

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
>   failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode:
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Have you any ideas, how can I fix this problem? Is there any other way to do same work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put baseURL:nil on

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>%@</body></html>",html] baseURL:nil];
```